# ubuntu22.04 pkcs11-tool --module /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so -L gemalto gemplus token not recognized

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu, smartcard

I'm trying to present a virtual smartcard to a ubuntu virtual machine. But the smartcard isn't recognized by the vm. Although an Almalinux 9 vm does recognize the virtual smartcard.

I'm using libvirt's smartcard module as described here [Smartcard Devices](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/virtualization_administration_guide/sub-section-libvirt-dom-xml-devices-smartcard). When I boot up a ubuntu 22.04 vm and run the command `pkcs11-tool --module /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so -L` I get the error

```
Slot 0 (0x0): Gemalto Gemplus USB SmartCard Reader 433-Swap [CCID interface...  
  (token not recognized)
```

--edit
It seems like the problem lies with the libccid library packaged with ubuntu 22.04 (libccid version 1.5.0-2). I compiled version 1.4.34 and replaced the libccid.so with my compiled version and then everything worked.  I don't know if there's a code regression in libccid, or if it was compiled wrong, or if it's just incompatible.

example output of the same command, but with the self compiled version of libccid.

```
Available slots:  
Slot 0 (0x0): Gemalto Gemplus USB SmartCard Reader 433-Swap [CCID Interface...
  token label        : cert1
  token manufacturer : Common Access Card
  token model        : PKCS#15 emulated
  token flags        : login required, PIN pad present, rng, token initialized, PIN initialized
  hardware version   : 0.0
  firmware version   : 0.0
  serial num         : 22ef84d3518c711b
  pin min/max        : 4/8
```

Comment: I assume you've checked for differences in the VM setup, so why not contrast differences between the GNU/Linux that works (ie. Alma Linux 9) & Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (*server or desktop; you didn't say*). As I (*possibly others on this site too*) know nothing about Alma Linux, it's where I'd look for clues (*if I can get anything to work on one GNU/Linux system, I'm convinced I can get it working on others if I want/need to*)